# Android - Firebase - Firestore: Is it possible to work only offline without synchronizing online?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in firestore (firebase),
is it possible to work only offline without synchronizing online?
Some users may not accept online storage.

Comment: If its offline then what's the use of keeping firebase in you app ? just create a local database in device memory and store it . but once the app is uninstalled the data is gone

Comment: to enable online synchronization, if possible

Comment: ok , but as I said above if data is not online then its lost once the app is uninstalled

Comment: by default it is useful online. some users can disable sync.
Is the solution having firestore and the local database?
for this reason I wanted to use Firestore online and offline